# Replace elements with another elements Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm getting the source of an image list, and i need replace that src on every element of the list.

This is my code so far:

```
    if($('#miniature-img').length){
    $('.prateleira-blog li').each(function(){

        var replaceCaratula = '<img src="' + $('#miniature-img img', this).attr('src').replace("-1000-1000", "") + '" >';

    });
}
```

If i put a console log, it prints all the image sources already changed. So, 'till here everything is working. Now, what i need is overwrite the old images tags with the new ones. I've tried with the next piece of code but without success:

```
$('.prateleira-blog li').each(function(index, replaceCaratula){
            $('#miniature-img img', this).replaceWith($(replaceCaratula));  
        });
```

The very first image tag appear in all the elements. What can i do to replace every new image tag over the old one?

I'm using Jquery and HTML.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Do you need to replace the entire `img` element or just the `src`? Can you include a snippet of HTML? You could probably just do `$(image selector).attr("src", function() { ... })` instead of `.each(...)`.

Comment: You need to iterate thru `#miniature-img img` not the `li` then change its src or the entire element depends on what you need

Comment: Please include your HTML. I feel like it would definitely clear up a good amount of the confusion here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want because your code is unclear and you haven't posted the HTML. So I can only guess what your setup is.

If you only want the images to change, then try only to change the src attribute. It will automatically load the new image:

```js
function changeImgs() {

  if($('#miniature-img').length){
    // read src attribute from the other image
    let source = $('#miniature-img').attr('src').replace('Original', 'Replaced');
    $('.prateleira-blog img').attr('src', source);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="miniature-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Original">
<br><br>
<div class="prateleira-blog">
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Original"></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Original"></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Original"></li>
</div>

<button onclick="changeImgs()">Change</button> <!-- Only for showing -->
```

Comment: why loop? just set the src

Comment: That's a good question. I've copied that part of his code because I wanted to change the least possible - I'll edit it anyways.